# перезаписывание целочисленного числа

Tags: c++, vector

Возник такой вопрос:
Я из переменной A вытаскиваю каждое значение и записываю его в вектор для дальнейший работы с ним. Суть проблемы в том, что например число `A = 10011101;` он записал в вектор нормально а такие числа `01101111` он записывает почему-то `794592`.
`101001110111 = -3-9-9-40-1-8-70-2`;

```
int a = 101001110111, b = 0, c = 2;
std::vector<int> abc;
std::vector<int> acb;
//int abc[3];
//int acb[3];
std::string buff;
std::string dd;

//int A = 524;



//for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    while (a / 10) {
            abc.push_back(a % 10);
            a /= 10;
}
    abc.push_back(a % 10);

b = abc.size();
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    acb.push_back(abc[b - i - 1]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    std::cout << abc[i];
}

std::cout << std::endl;
system("pause");
```

Comment: как ты вообще в int записал такое число "01101111"?

Comment: а отладчик чего говорит????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Целочисленные литералы, начинающиеся с 0, рассматриваются компилятором как запись числа в восьмеричной системе исчисления.

Например. литерал

```
016
```

есть значение 8 + 6 = 14 в десятичной системе исчисления.

Также может иметь место переполнение, когда заданный литерал не умещается в объекте заданного типа. Используйте тип `unsigned long long`, если хотите хранить большие целые числа.

Вы можете проверить, сколько десятичных цифр может гарантированно иметь объект того или иного целочисленного типа. Ниже показана демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits10 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Например при запуске ее с помощью online-компилятора на www.ideone.com получается следующий рзультат

```
9
19
```

Если ваш компьютер поддерживает двоичные литералы и вы хотите представить запись литералов в виде двоичных литералов, то вы можете использовать их. Например

```
int x = 0b101001110111;
```

Или при выполнении данного фрагмента кода

```
int x = 0b011;

std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

будет выведено число 3.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что число `101001110111` слишком велико, чтобы записать его в переменную типа `int`. На типичном настольном компьютере с архитектурой x86_64 `int` имеет размер 32 бита, т.е. вмещает числа в диапазоне от `–2,147,483,648` до `2,147,483,647`. Ваше число слишком велико, поэтому когда вы присваиваете его переменной `a` происходит целочисленное переполнение, результат которого имеет неопределенный результат (т.е. является ошибочным по определению).

Чтобы гарантировать что переменная сможет вместить ваше число, вам необходимо воспользоваться типом `int64_t` из заголовка `<cstdint>`, либо типом `long long` из нового стандарта C++11.

*Добавлено*: что касается примера с `01101111`, то это число, как указано в соседнем ответе @Vlad from Moscow, считается восьмеричным, поэтому результат был для вас неожиданным.

Comment: В 64-битовой ОС объекты типа int могут иметь 64 бита. Все зависит от ОС.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Это также зависит от компилятора. Но на настольных компьютерах с x86 `int` как правило 32-битный, даже если это 64-разрядная система. Это справедливо для Windows/MSVC, Linux/GCC и MacOS X/GCC.